# How to tell TS that the property exists

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to tell Typescript that the property I'm trying to access is not `null/undefined`.

I'm aware of

- `?` optional chain operator
- `!` non-null assertion operator

Here is what I'm trying to do

```js
type UpsertRequestType = {
  per_page?: number;
  page_window?: number;
};

type SettingsCollectionType = {
  _id: string;
  per_page: number;
  page_window: number;
};

class Settings {
  constructor(private readonly settingsRepository: Mongo.Collection<SettingsCollectionType>) {}

  private get settings() {
    return this.settingsRepository.findOne({}) || null;
  }

  upsert(payload: Optional<UpsertRequestType>): void;
  upsert(payload: Required<UpsertRequestType>): void;
  upsert(payload: unknown): void {
    if (this.settings) return this.update(<Optional<UpsertRequestType>>payload);

    return this.insert(<Required<UpsertRequestType>>payload);
  }

  private update(payload: Optional<UpsertRequestType>): void {
    this.settingsRepository.update({ _id: this.settings!._id }, { $set: payload });
  }

  private insert(payload: Required<UpsertRequestType>): void {
    this.settingsRepository.insert(payload);
  }
}
```

As you can see I am using `this.settings!._id` with `!` symbol to clarify that `_id` is there for sure. However, is there another way that TS can infer this behavior automatically?

It is pretty obvious that when I check `if(this.settings)` it is not definitely `null/undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `this.settings!._id` is inside the `update` method, and the method is called inside the `if` statement, but TypeScript cannot be sure that you will never call `update` outside of it, thus it considers that `this.settings` might be `undefined`.

I don't think that you have an easy way of avoiding the `!` syntax, so I would probably just keep it as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it, you are specifying that `this.settings` exists, what you want to actually do is:

`this.settings!._id!` so you specify that both `settings` and `_id` are not `null` (or `undefined`).

The exclamation mark operator is always put after the property you want to assert is not null, for a very specific reason:

```js
let temp?: number = null

/*code happens here*/
if(temp! < 3)
// ...
```

In this case you couldn't really do something like: `this!.temp`

Comment: That property is `this.settings` in my case. `this.settings._id!` won't work but this is not a point. I was looking for a solution that can autoinfer. `this.settings!._id` works just fine without extra `!` in the end.

Comment: Oh pardon me, I've misunderstood the question then!

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, the `settings()` getter could be null. You should specify the return value of the get function to be non-nullish so you won't need to use the `!` operator.

Comment: Well, that could one way of doing it but I will need to typecast it.